# Can't play Native DSD /w Topping D10 USB DAC

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04, alsa

I'm a complete linux newbie and have just installed Ubuntu 20.04. In my prior OS windows, I was using Foobar2000 and was able to play DSD files natively. The DAC would display a change in the sample rate with different tracks. Now instead it sticks at 48000 PCM regardless of what I am playing and when I play my DSD files, it plays it at 48000. How do I get my DAC to play DSD natively again ?

```
lsusb : Bus 001 Device 005: ID 152a:8750 Thesycon Systemsoftware & Consulting GmbH D10

aplay -l :
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: D10 [D10], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Please let me know if more information is required from me. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using the default Ubuntu configuration, then it's likely that PulseAudio uses a common sample rate in order to be able to mix multiple streams together.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply, I was 'sort of' able to resolve it. I ended up using MDP/NCMPCPP to play all my audio files. What i had to do was to ammend the mdp.conf file to allow it to play variable sample rates. Still works at a constant 44.1khz for everything else. The following was what i changed in the .conf file :

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply, I was 'sort of' able to resolve it. I ended up using MDP/NCMPCPP to play all my audio files. What i had to do was to ammend the mdp.conf file to allow it to play variable sample rates (Audio Output {...format          "*:*:*"} ) Still works at a constant 44.1khz for everything else.

As the following :

audio_output {

type "alsa"

name "USB DAC Topping D10"

device "hw:1,0"

mixer_type      "hardware"

mixer_control   "DIGITAL"

auto_resample   "no"

auto_format     "no"

enabled         "yes"

format          "*:*:*"

}

Sourced the solution from the MDP wiki/documentation.